# Aplicar uma função usando algumas colunas de todas as linhas de um Dataframe (r)

Tags: r, data.frame, apply

Eu tenho o seguinte Dataframe :

```
                AVG_VOLUME   AVG_RETURN  VOL     PRICE
SPX Index       500000       0.01        0.08    2082
KR7000270009    6000         0.02        0.09    102
KR7005930003    7000         0.02        0.08    103
JP3266400005    8000         0.03        0.08    104
KYG875721634    9000         0.04        0.08    105
JP3900000005    10           0.05        0.08    106
```

Estou tentando aplicar a função GBM do pacote sde usando os dados de cada linha do DataFrame :

```
GBM(x=1, r=0, sigma=1, T=1, N=100)
Arguments
x initial value of the process at time t0.
r the interest rate of the GBM.
sigma the volatility of the GBM.
T final time.
N number of intervals in which to split [t0,T]
```

Tentei utilizar apply mas acredito que estou errando em algum lugar :

```
Test <- apply(Stock_Info,1,function(x) {
        GBM(x[,"PRICE"],x[,"AVG_RETURN"],x[,"VOL"],1,252) 
})
```

Qual a correta forma de aplicar apply nesse caso ? Ou alguma outra forma de aplicar essa função nas colunas destacadas acima em todas as linhas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você poderia usar o `apply` neste caso sim, o problema no seu código atual é o seguinte: dentro do `apply` o `x` que você está passando para sua função não é mais um `data.frame` e sim um vetor. Dessa forma, ao invés de `x[,"PRICE"]` você teria que passar `x["PRICE"]` e assim por diante.

Usando seus dados de exemplo:

```
Stock_Info <- read.table(text ="AVG_VOLUME   AVG_RETURN  VOL     PRICE
  500000       0.01        0.08    2082
    6000         0.02        0.09    102
    7000         0.02        0.08    103
    8000         0.03        0.08    104
    9000         0.04        0.08    105
    10           0.05        0.08    106", header = TRUE)


library("sde")
test <- apply(Stock_Info,1,function(x) {
  GBM(x["PRICE"],x["AVG_RETURN"],x["VOL"],1,252) 
})
```